# Bootstrap button outline not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new to Bootstrap, and am having a bit of trouble with getting my buttons styled correctly. I want a green(success) colored button, with just an outline as documented on their website [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#outline-buttons). When I use the code suggested `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline">Success</button>`, I get a grey button that has no apparent styling [which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnA46.png)... Could anybody help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: `outline` is for bootstrap [v-4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#outline-buttons), it looks like you're trying to use it with [v-3](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

Comment: That was it. Thanks! That's somewhat embarrassing.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us at some point.

Comment: This was not working for me because of bootstrap optional theme css i imported. It was part of my html template. Removed it and it worked correctly.

Comment: It's actually `btn-outline-success` [check the guides](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/)

Comment: Why is there `twitter-bootstrap-3` tag for `bootstrap v4 alpha` question?

Answer (score 13):

I've been having a similar issue. You can just set up a rule in CSS to what it should be OR override the 'btn-success-outline' class.

```
/*Bootstrap button outline override*/
.btn-outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.btn-primary.btn-outline {
    color: #428bca;
}

.btn-success.btn-outline {
    color: #5cb85c;
}

.btn-info.btn-outline {
    color: #5bc0de;
}

.btn-warning.btn-outline {
    color: #f0ad4e;
}

.btn-danger.btn-outline {
    color: #d9534f;
}

.btn-primary.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-success.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-info.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-warning.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-danger.btn-outline:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

If you choose the first option with the above CSS, in your html use:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-outline">success</button>
```

Comment: Cool, use this for bootstrap v3.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that bootstrap css files works? Because in that code `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline">Success</button>` it does not specify anything but btn-success-outline (what you said). You should check if your css files works or the other bootstrap documents. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

the reason your's is not working is that it is btn-outline-success not btn-success-outline.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap 3 it won't work either this is a bootstrap 4 like vanburen mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Chrome button-outline compatibility issue: in your code `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline">Success</button>` with bootstrap > 4.1.x I found that including `type="button"`will break the outline effect on Chrome, but it works in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class for outline.

It should be `btn-outline-success`.

Nothing is wrong with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using older version of Bootstrap. Go to https://getbootstrap.com/ and update your link

Answer (score -1):

**If Your Bootstrap work fine. Than You can try this code.**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline">Success</button>
```

plz check your parent div. Is this div use the Float css. If use float than btn need clear:both;